# How to clear AntDesign select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I use React Ant Design and i need to clear selected value in AntD select. 
How can i do this without using value prop ?

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-sinoussi-0pb1r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try prop `allowClear` of `Select`

```
<Select
   mode="tags"
   style={{ width: "100%" }}
   onChange={handleChange}
   tokenSeparators={[","]}
   allowClear
>
  {children}
</Select>
```

[image]

Comment: Will onChange gets triggered on clicking the clear